# Webpage with multiple video player windows

Tags: video

I'm looking for any examples on the internet where someone may have done something similar already?....I'd like a webpage that displays multiple video player windows in a single row alongside each other taking up all the page from left to right (there would be space above and below). The windows wouldn't have to be very big and I'm not too sure how many would fit onscreen but I'm more concerned with getting the functionality working at the moment. Only one of these windows would be playing a clip of just a few seconds then when that one finished, the next short clip in the window to the right would begin and so on. It would always be the window in the centre of the page playing so they would all shift from right to left until there were no more.
If anyone knows any similar examples already out there I would be keen to know or if anyone could give me any pointers on how I might achieve this it would be greatly appreciated!
Regards, Carlos

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple jquery plugin that uses video.js to achieve this. All you need to do is decide your template, and provide the list of videos. I suggest studying the code to understand how this has been done. https://github.com/buttflattery/idows-videojs-videowall